# ActiveX ComboBox method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, methods, combobox, member

I have a combobox (called `userBox`) within a sheet called `Home`. It has one of the options selected, let's say `"User A"`. All I'm trying to do is assign `"User A"` to string `usr`, but I keep getting the compile error:

> Method or data member not found

```
Sub fixPls()
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer, usr As String, tbl As String, found  As Boolean, k As Integer, payType As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Home")
ws.Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = Range("B16").End(xlUp).row
usr = ws.userBox.Value
tbl = ws.tblBox.Value
payType = ws.tpBox.Value
....
```

EDIT: I tried a dummy program in a new workbook, and it worked. Using an activeX comboBox, why is it different?

```
Sub blah()
Dim rly As String
rly = Sheets(1).ComboBox1.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 10) = rly 
End Sub
```

Cell J1 returns the value selecting in the comboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an ActiveX control, you need to use the `OLEObjects` collection to access it:

```
Debug.Print ws.OLEObjects("userBox").Object.Text
```

Comment: Sorry I've edited the post since then. My dummy program works when using an ActiveX combobox and extracting the value using the .combobox.value within the sheet's scope.

Comment: You can't use a `Worksheet` object to access an `OLEObject` like you're doing in your first example. If you declare your worksheet as `Variant` or `Object` instead, it should work. Or, just use `OLEObjects()`, as I've shown above, which is the recommended way to access ActiveX controls. Then it will work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure it out, but the solution is simple, just disable trusted documents:
File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings – Go to “Trusted Documents” and click on the button to “Disable Trust Documents”  Close Excel and re-open.